# pnpm add <package_name> updating all packages

Tags: pnpm

when running `pnpm add <package_name>` all my packages get updated, same thing happens when running `pnpm install <package_name>`.

is there a flag or configuration I can use to stop this from happening?

using `pnpm` version 7.14.2.

Comment: Can you share your package.json and the lock file? What package are you installing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://pnpm.io/cli/install :

> --prefer-offline
>
> Default: false
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If true, staleness checks for cached data will be bypassed, but missing data will be requested from the server. To force full offline mode, use --offline.

From the source code:
https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/blob/eacff33e4f77cf550e4da4f3e7f4506200a93154/packages/pnpm/src/main.ts#L228-L238

```js
    if (
      config.updateNotifier !== false &&
      !isCI &&
      !selfUpdate &&
      !config.offline &&
      !config.preferOffline &&
      !config.fallbackCommandUsed &&
      (cmd === 'install' || cmd === 'add')
    ) {
      checkForUpdates(config).catch(() => { /* Ignore */ })
    }
```

`pnpm install --prefer-offline <package_name>` will prevent pnpm from checking for updates, but will still request the data you need from the server.